# How is it possible to return a Future<T> in a Future<void> in Dart?

Tags: dart

```
Future<void> foo() {
        final futureInt = Future.value(2);
        return futureInt;
      }
```

How is the above code possible? the return value is a Future of type int, while the specified value of foo is Future of type void?

Also, when adding the async keyword to the function, it doesn't even run anymore (using dartpad), why is that? (check attachment)

[the error is : A value of type 'Future' can't be returned from the function 'foo' because it has a return type of 'Future'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3XD7.png)

I tried return the Future value directly and the error disappears:

```
Future<void> foo() async {
        final futureInt = Future.value(2);
        return Future.value(2);
      }
```

No error from this code. I can't seem to understand the difference here also between returning futureInt (which gives an error) and Future.value(2) (which works perfectly)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, `void` is essentially a *top-type*, meaning that all values can in theory be assigned to `void`. This is why a `Future<int>` is a subtype of a `Future<void>` and can be returned in the non-`async` method.

However, when `void` is used as a return type it gets a special meaning: It indicates that the method should not return a value. The compiler checks this, which is why it's an error to write things like:

```dart
void foo() {
  return 2;
}
```

As far as the compiler is generally concerned, a `Future<void>` is *not* the same thing as `void`, so you can return a value in the non-asynchronous function.

With `async` functions, the situation is a bit different. They have to return a future, and so the compiler applies something known as "flattening": In an asynchronous method returning a `Future<T>`, the language mandates that either a `Future<T>` or a direct `T` is returned. So, in asynchronous functions, the `Future<void>` behaves like a `void` in synchronous functions. This is why it's suddenly forbidden to return the `Future<int>`.

When returning a `Future.value(2)`, you're not directly specifying the future's type. By looking at the expected return type (which is `Future<void>`), the compiler infers that you're returning a `Future<void>.value(2)`. This is perfectly legal because here, the `2` is not returned directly and `int` is a subtype of `void`.

As you'd expect, the following snippet is indeed forbidden:

```dart
Future<void> foo() async {
  final futureInt = Future.value(2);
  return Future<int>.value(2);
}
```

So, to summarize:

1. When not used as a return value, anything can be assigned to `void`.
2. Methods declared to return `void` can't return non-void values.
3. `async` methods returned to `Future<void>` also can't return non-void values.

Comment: it is worth nothing that using this code Future<void> foo() async {
  final futureInt = Future.value(2);
  return Future<int>.value(2);
} in dart version >=2.18.5 returns an error, however, using it with the dart version >=2.6.0 works fine and does not cause any error. Also, the code you mentioned returns an error in dartpad so i guess it depends on the dart version being used.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution**

Instead of using *Future< void>*, use **Future< dynamic>**

that's it.